# Eigenvectors for prime numbers matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, prime-numbers

I have noticed that eigenvectors for matrices $2\times{2}$ made from $4$ consecutive **big** prime numbers, for example

$\begin{bmatrix}
100003 & 100019 \\
100043 &100049 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$,

have "always" approximate eigenvectors  presented below in the matrix

$R=\begin{bmatrix}
  v_1 & v_2 \\
 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}  &-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
 \end{bmatrix} = Rotation(\pi/4) $

I suppose it's  not only characteristic for prime numbers but also for any big numbers with relatively small differences between consecutive numbers, but ....

- how to prove that it holds just for 4 consecutive big prime numbers?

What are consequences of these approximate eigenvector forms?

*P.S.

 Please notice dear reader that I'm not asking whether property I have presented is valid **exclusively** for primes numbers (big ones), but ..  whether it is valid **also** for big prime numbers in any situation what requires however a little analysis of prime numbers properties.*
For example to use [Legendre conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dividing your matrix by the first entry won't change anything. When you do, it has the form 
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 + a \\
1 + b & 1 + c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a, b, c$ are all small numbers. Hence it's almost symmetric, hence has almost orthogonal eigenvectors.

Now look at

$$
M\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
1 
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2+a  \\
2+(b+c) 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since $a,b,c$ are small, this vector is *almost* an eigenvector of eigenvalue 2. Similarly, $$\begin{bmatrix}
-1  \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}$$
will almost be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$.

And that explains what you're seeing. It turns out to have nothing to do with prime-ness --- just the fact that your four numbers are close to each other.

Comment: Ok. I have taken this into account but how to prove that it is satisfied **just** for **prime numbers**. Can we prove that they have sufficiently "small" differences for this formula to hold? This is my question..

Comment: The prime number theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) says that the gap between successive primes is, on average, much smaller than the primes themselves. That average isn't universally true (there may be long spans with no primes), but then again, your formula probably isn't either (exactly in those places). See the facts on "prime gaps" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) for more details. Since prime gaps have asymptotic bounds that ensure that for large enough primes, $a,b,c$ are small, your conjecture is true for large enough primes.

Comment: To answer your last question about "what's the significance of this?", I cannot see any, since it appears to be a far weaker statement than the known results on the distribution of primes and the sizes of prime gaps.

Comment: Hmm, so you are skeptical whether it holds for the case  where gap occurs... If it were we would have known that the big gaps can be only for much bigger numbers (how many times?) than the gap is.

Comment: I'm not skeptical about anything here. But even if I were, it wouldn't matter --- the claim is true or false, regardless of my state of mind. Look, you can plot, for various values of $a,b,c$, the angle between the dominant eigenvector and $[1,1]$. That'll tell you how large a gap is needed (and between which two primes) to make you feel that the eigenvector is no longer "approximately" $[1,1]$ (I can't do that part -- you're the only just of "approximately"!). That'll tell you "how many times". And the results on upper bounds on gaps will give you some sense of whether such gaps ever occur.

Comment: @Ok.JohnHughes, Ok. If someone knows an example where this approximation evidently fails I will be very grateful... from my observations it seems to be on average better and better when prime number increases..

Comment: I wonder whether  assuming that the gap between primes for maximal number $= n$  in series can't be greater than $\sqrt{n}$ it would not be sufficient to prove the case...

Comment: From wikipedia: One can deduce that the gaps get arbitrarily smaller in proportion to the primes: the quotient  gap to number   
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g_n}{p_n}=0.$

Guido Hoheisel  (1930) was the first to show that there exists a constant $θ < 1$ such that

$\pi(x + x^\theta) - \pi(x) \sim \frac{x^\theta}{\log(x)} \text{ as } x \to \infty$

hence showing that

$g_n<p_n^\theta,\,$

 .....

A result, due to Baker, [ Glyn Harman|Harman ] and [  János Pintz|Pintz ] in 2001, shows that $θ$ may be taken to be $0.525$.

Comment: I accepted your answer John however your final conclusion is not good written. You wrote "It turns out to have nothing to do with prime-ness --- just the fact that your four numbers are close to each other" .   ...... ,, should not be rather "It turns out  that it is connected with the fact that your four numbers are close to each other, the primes are close too each other so for primes it is also applicable". Could be the possibility to change this final phrase? In present form it contorts my original intention of the question .. please John change it if possible, it's important.

Answer (score 4):

May be it is just because: $$
\begin{bmatrix} a &b \\ c &d \end{bmatrix}
$$ has roughly eigenvectors (not normalized) $\langle 1, 1 \rangle$ and $\langle 1, -1 \rangle$ if $$
a+b \approx c+d \\
b-a \approx c-d
$$ The first eqn holds because, in your setting of 4 large primes, $a,b,c,d$ are large and their difference relatively small. 
The second does not always hold. Why do you think so? If you apply (multiply) the matrix on $\langle 1, -1 \rangle$, you get $\langle -16, -6 \rangle$, which is not good likeness to $\langle 1, -1 \rangle$ itself.

Comment: What do you mean by substitution <-1,1>  in the matrix?

Comment: sorry, I meant multiply the matrix by <-1,1>. Edited.

Comment: I see, but (-1,1) is only close approximation not exact value, so for such big numbers have decisive meaning... but your remark is very valuable..

Comment: Well, basically @John Hughes is saying the same thing as me

Comment: Yes, it's true., but both of you don't clearly said that it is applicable for primes because they are **sufficiently** close to each other.. (John gave in comments some links to wikipedia when it is written so with this his answer can be accepted).